# Error Django: Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django

No puedo hacer que funcione mi url de formulario en django.
Descripcion del error:

> Using the URLconf defined in django1_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>     1. ^admin/
>     2. ^mascota ^$ [name='index']
>     3. ^mascota ^nuevo$ [name='mascotaView']
>     4. ^mascota ^mascota/nuevo$ [name='mascotaView']
>     5. ^adopcion
>   The current URL, mascota/nuevo, didn't match any of these.
>
> You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Mi archivo `URL.PY` dentro de la carpeta del proyecto de django:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from apps.mascota.views import index, mascotaView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', index,name='index'),
    url(r'^nuevo$',mascotaView,name='mascotaView'),
    url(r'^mascota/nuevo$',mascotaView,name='mascotaView'),
]
```

Mi archivo `URL.PY` dentro de la carpeta raiz del proyecto general de django:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^mascota', include('apps.mascota.urls', namespace='mascota')),
    url(r'^adopcion', include('apps.adopcion.urls',namespace='adopcion')),
]
```

No puedo encontrar el error. ¿Cual sería la causa de que no me encuntre la url http: //127.0.0.1:8000/mascota/nuevo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu archivo url dentro de la carpeta raiz modificalo a:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^mascota/', include('apps.mascota.urls', namespace='mascota')),
    url(r'^adopcion', include('apps.adopcion.urls',namespace='adopcion')), ]
```

Nota la "/" al final de mascota esto indica que todas las urls que incluiras en tu archivos de apps.mascota.urls les va anteponer la "/"